# insert data into a lot of columns in java JDBC

Tags: java, jdbc, insert, hashmap

I have a table with 50 columns and I want to insert all items in a `HashMap` variable into it (`HashMap` keys and table column names are the same).
How can I do that without writing 50 lines of code?

Answer (score 3):

Get the key set for the HashMap. Iterate that key set to build a String containing your insert statement. Use the resulting String to create a PreparedStatement. Then iterate that key set again to set parameters by name using the Objects you retrieve from the HashMap.

You might have to write a few extra lines of special-case code if any of your values are of a Class that the JDBC driver isn't sure how to map.

Comment: Few things that seem a bit wrong to me: 1. keys aren't ordered in any way in a HashMap, so you won't know which one is the first you'll get; and PreparedStatement only allows you to set its parameters based on index values; 2. column names have no additional meta information about its types, so I'm unsure if calling `setObject` for every parameter will work.

Comment: Does iterating in KeySet of a HashMap always in one order? I mean if I get create column portion of SQL insert code, has the values the same order?

Comment: +1 to darioo .. you are absolutely correct on both counts. Changes I would make would be to use the key set to instantiate an ArrayList and then use that to both build the PreparedStatement's sql string, and then set parameters by index.

Comment: @darioo: 1) the unordered nature of a `HashMap` can be suppressed by constructing a `LinkedHashMap` based on it. 2) calling `setObject()` will definitely work if you use the appropriate value type, e.g. `String`, `Integer`, `Date`, etc. The JDBC driver wil do the type checking.

Comment: @BalusC: thanks for clearing that up. Although I wouldn't feel too safe using that approach since your intentions aren't clearly expressed code wise and this might lead to some hard to find bugs in the future if one isn't careful enough.

Comment: @darioo: Can't agree more :) I'd after all just go for an ORM.

Comment: A hashmap's iteration order remains constant if the contents don't change.  The suggested solution in the answer will work fine.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you bite the dust and simply write a method that will do the dirty work for you containing 50 lines of parameter setting code. This isn't so bad, and you only have to write it once. I hope you aren't that lazy ;-)

And by the way, isn't 50 columns in a table a bit much? Perhaps a normalization process could help and lower complexity of your database and the code that will manipulate it.

Another way to go is to use an ORM like [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/), or a more lightweight approach like [Spring JDBC template](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html).

Answer (score 2):

1. Call `map.keySet()` to get the name of all columns.
2. Create an INSERT statement by iterating the key set.

   - The column is from an item (a key) in the key set.
   - The data is from `map.get(key)`.